# Lookup of objectsid slow in ACL view

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

We have a performance problem in with active directory 2003: reverse lookup of object sids, particularly in ACLs and quotas, is very slow. Looking up user names in a long quota list may well take several hours; lookup of all users in an ACL can take 20s.

By contrast, performing a programmatic lookup (performing an LDAP search of objectSid) completes very fast.

What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: Is one of your domain controllers connected via WAN or is everything in LAN? Also: is this a single domain or are the lookups performed over a forest/domain trust?

Comment: Is it consistent? Or is it only ACL's in ADUC, are there any patterns to this?

Comment: It's a single domain, on a LAN. I couldn't spot any pattern in it.